# Handle to "Copy" & "Define" Popover Menu Items

Tags: ios5, uiwebview, uimenucontroller

Trying to do some work with text selected in a UIWebView. There are 2 buttons that pop over:

Copy and Define

[image]

At a very high level, how can I do the following?

1) Grab the value of the text selected

2) Add another menu item

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`UIMenuController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html) singleton is the black popup with the buttons, and the documentation has good information on how to work with that (presenting it manually, adding new items, responding to actions, etc).

As for getting the selected text, I see you're using an editable div in a `UIWebView`, which means you have to respond to editing actions via JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial answers your questions in detail :)

http://ios-blog.co.uk/category/tutorials/rich-text-editing-a-simple-start-part-1/

Specifically, for adding a menu item, do something like the following from part 3. Place the following in the root view controller's implementation file:

```
UIMenuItem *highlightMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Highlight"  action:@selector(highlight)];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:highlightMenuItem]];
```

with the highlight method as follows:

```
- (void)highlight {
    NSString *currentColor = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.queryCommandValue('backColor')"];
    if ([currentColor isEqualToString:@"rgb(255, 255, 0)"]) {
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand('backColor', false, 'white')"];
    } else {
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand('backColor', false, 'yellow')"];
    }
}
```

Comment: While that tutorial has some good information, it is also full of some really dirty dirty hacks and bad practices.  You should take most of what you read in there with a large grain of salt.